# Include Paypal IPN entire return data to your SQL 'insert into'

Tags: php, mysql, paypal, paypal-ipn

I am already successful at making Paypal's IPN connect to my ipn.php and then store parts of IPN data like payment_status and payer_email into my database' table columns. What I want, if possible, is to store the main (non-concatenated) IPN string into one of my row's column in database. Is that possible? So far I'm successful because of StackOverflow. I hope you can help me with this one too. I have a column named IPNLogs which stores each IPN strings I get from Paypal. I'll use it incase of tracking issue reports. Don't ask me why this way or give me other options to track please, I need it this way for other purposes or usage.:)

Comment: What's your issue? You're adding a string value to a string column? How long is the string you're trying to store, and what's the column type?

Comment: **I'm trying to store the entire IPN string. Example below is the IPN string, there any way to store or insert that into my database as well? So I can check this which serves as IPNLog to investigate transaction issues.**

 array (
  'mc_gross' => '50.00',
  'tax' => '0.00',
  'payment_status' => 'Completed',
  'quantity' => '1',
  'payment_fee' => '',
  'shipping_discount' => '0.00',
  'insurance_amount' => '0.00',
  'shipping_method' => 'Default',
  'handling_amount' => '0.00',
  'payment_gross' => '',
  'shipping' => '0.00',
  'ipn_track_id' => 'asdaasdagasdwasd',
 )

Comment: If that's the case, then you need a `TEXT` field, not `VARCHAR` and some way of serializing the PHP `array` into a string. One way that works is to save it in the database [as JSON](http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php).

Answer (score -1):

In your "ipn.php", if you are using curl to receive Paypal server's response, then here is the solution for you:

$res = curl_exec($ch);
......
$query = "INSERT INTO payments
             (IPNLogs, ......)
             VALUES
             ('$res', ......)";
......

Comment: Uh oh, no I don't think I use curl. The code below works, whenever Paypal sends an IPN string and my ipn.php processes it, it also creates a textfile in my server and that file contains the entire IPN string. I was hoping to be able to store it into the table as well.

     **file_put_contents('IpnQuerryLog.txt',var_export($_POST,true));**

Comment: You **must** escape any and all values you put in your query string. This is unbelievably bad.